# Replaying the Bad Parity Hack

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-invocation, delegatecall

On a locally hosted instance of Ethererum I am trying to replay and understand the Bad Parity hack. I have a Wallet and a Wallet Library Contract.

Wallet.sol

```
constructor(address lib) public payable {
    walletLibrary = lib; 
    walletLibrary.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address)")), msg.sender);
}


function () public payable {
    emit LogValue(301,msg.value);
    walletLibrary.delegatecall(msg.data);
}
```

I want to fetch all the coins by resetting the owner with the fallback Method.

WalletLibrary

```
function initWallet(address _owner) public payable {
   owner = _owner;
}
```

My idea is to call the fallback method with Remix with the following parameters:

bytes4(keccak256("initWallet(address)")), msg.sender);

I manually computed bytes4 and keccak with the web3 console, is this approach correct?